# How do I rename a file using cfzip?

Tags: coldfusion, zip, rename, coldfusion-10, cfzip

I'm having difficulty to rename a file when a document is zipped. Right below, I'm trying to get strings from a document, replace and save as a document with UUID file name. I would like the name of the file to be changed as something that is readable when the file is zipped. How can I do it?

```
<cfset rtf = FileRead(filepathofdocument) />
<cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%newProdYN%",session.input.inputtext) />
<cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,"%ration%",session.input.inputtext2) />
<cfset cfdest = "#GetDirectoryFromPath(session.input.storage.destination)#/#CreateUUID()#.doc" />
<cffile action = "write" 
    file = "#cfdest#"
    output = "#rtf#">
<cfzip action="zip" file="#getTempDirectory()#/#CreateUUID()#.zip">
<cfzipparam source="#cfdest#" entrypath="document.doc" />
<!-- More file sources to zip... -->
</cfzip>
```

The entry path of `cfzipparam` tag does not seem to work...

Edited: I have actually follow the tutorial by Ben Nadel blog. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/795-learning-coldfusion-8-cfzip-part-ii-zipping-files-and-directories-with-cfzipparam.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot rename the files inside a zip using `cfzip`.
Providing an entrypath in `cfzipparam` will only create a subdirectory inside the zip file.
In your case the sub-directory named 'document.doc' will be created inside the zip file.
The name of the file inside the zip will be the same as you provided in `cffile` while generating the doc file.
[Please read this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7693.html)

So you need to first rename the file as desired. And then you can zip it to get the desired results.

Comment: My upvote got your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Yes Pankaj, I am coming to your home for my beer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `entrypath` attribute allows you to rename the file that will be included in the zip.

Unfortunately there seems to be a [bug #3968971](http://coldfusion215.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=25624081&item=1048) in ColdFusion 11 where this has stopped working.